# In PHP, is writing a variable (already instantiated and set to a value) without assignment a syntactically valid statement? (eg. $My_Variable;)

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment

I have a standardised build process in PHP in which the usual penultimate output is a **PHP array**.

My intention is *always* to return a **JSON string**, so it's normal, at the end of the standardised build process to include the following lines:

```
// STRINGIFY DATA
$My_Data = json_encode($My_Data);

// SEND DATA
return $My_Data;
```

For the first time, I have a build process where the penultimate output is *already* a **JSON String**.

For standardisation purposes I still want to include the `// STRINGIFY DATA` step.

But I don't really want to use:

```
// STRINGIFY DATA
$My_Data = json_encode(json_decode($My_Data, TRUE));
```

if I can avoid it.

Is it syntactically valid to state the variable without assignment?

```
// STRINGIFY DATA
$My_Data;
```

What does PHP do when it sees an already instantiated variable which already has a value... and that's the entire statement?

The above does not appear to break the script, but is PHP doing any processing?

Or does it pay not much more regard to the above than it would a comment?

Comment: I don't get the purpose of `$My_Data;` statement. What task it should solve?

Comment: It’s a valid statement, same as `5;` or `'foo';` …

Comment: @u_mulder - if `// STRINGIFY DATA` is missing then it might indicate an accidental omission, which might be an error. If it's present, then we can be confident that it hasn't been accidentally missed out.

Comment: @u_mulder Looks like OP wants to maintain the coding standard /convention used throughout the app. But since the variable already contains a json string, there's no reason to encode. So OP wonders if it's "safe" to just put `$My_Data;` there instead and if PHP does something with that or not.

Comment: Who or what are you expecting to make use of that information? If this is just for the human reader, then following this line with another comment, `// not necessary here, because input data already is JSON`, would achieve about the same thing, but without any “no-op”.

Comment: I suppose PHP notices the variable, but since there's no assignment and no statement to print or anything, the PHP interpreter just moves on.

Comment: Please share more details - what do you want to achieve? "What does PHP do" looks like something you could simply check by running that script

Comment: @CBroe - I want to be able to validate build processes computationally, regardless of who has written them. To date the value of the `// STRINGIFY DATA` section has always been `$My_Data = json_encode($My_Data);` I can mess around with conditions / ternaries etc. (and I've already experimented with that) but that can get convoluted very quickly. Instead a second possible value (`$My_Data;`) suits perfectly. Now the validator knows it's looking for either of two tightly defined values.

Comment: @icecub - Thank you. You summarised everything perfectly. :D

Comment: @Nico Haase - PHP didn't appear to do anything. But I'm not so naive to think that just because PHP didn't _appear_ to do anything, that means it didn't. CBroe and icecub very kindly gave me the reassurance I was looking for that such a statement is valid and does nothing.

Comment: Why not simply make an if statement there that checks if the input is a valid json string or not and then encodes or not based on it? That way you can maintain the same code everywhere.

Comment: Fair point, @icecub. I tried that before coming here. But I quickly realised I have to distinguish between 1) something that is a PHP array and can be stringified; 2) something which is JSON and has already been stringified and 3) something which is neither a PHP array nor valid JSON - as I mentioned above, it got convoluted quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it syntactically valid to state the variable without assignment?

Yes. As you found yourself, it doesn't give a syntax error. That's because [the definition of "statement"](https://heap.space/xref/php-src/Zend/zend_language_parser.y?r=8b37c1e9#478) in PHP's parser include `expr ';'` as one of its expansions. In other words, every expression in PHP is a valid statement. The [definition of `expr`](https://heap.space/xref/php-src/Zend/zend_language_parser.y?r=8b37c1e9#1016) unsurprisingly has `variable` as its first expansion - a variable on its own is a valid expression.

(As a side note, in some languages, statements and expressions are completely equivalent; in PHP, there are constructs which are valid *statements* but cannot be used as *expressions*.)

> is PHP doing any processing?

We can find this out by looking at the "op codes" generated (the intermediary high-level language which PHP is compiled to). For instance, running the following:

```php
$a = 42;
$foo;
$b = 69;
```

The "Vulcan Logic Debugger" [incorporated into this site](https://3v4l.org/IOPmC/vld#output) shows:

```
number of ops:  3
compiled vars:  !0 = $a, !1 = $foo, !2 = $b
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   ASSIGN                                                   !0, 42
   5     1        ASSIGN                                                   !2, 69
   6     2      > RETURN                                                   1
```

Note that the compiler has allocated a "compiled var" for `$foo` (`!1 = $foo`) but the only actual operations generated are the assignments to `$a` and `$b`. It's therefore safe to say that no operation will happen at run-time when the line `$foo;` is reached.